# Booting without network configuration

Tags: configuration, networking

I use a PC and a laptop both on Ubuntu 11.10. PC uses internet with lan cable from ADSL modem while laptop uses wifi. Only in my laptop I get this message that booting without network configuration. This adds upto my laptop boot up time. My PC having lesser RAM boots almost 2 mins faster than laptop. What should I do to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is already a bug report for this problem on Launchpad and you should be able to solve it as suggested in the comment 40 of the bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/856810

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment everything related to non-active connections in your /etc/network/interfaces file :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# keep the loopback interface, really usefull

# auto eth0
# iface eth0 inet dhcp
# address 192.168.0.2
# netmask 255.255.255.0
# gateway 192.168.0.1
# broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

and you should manage all your network connection with the Network Manager (the `/etc/network/interfaces` is usefull for servers, not for desktop machines).